# Singleton List in Abstract Class ... Am I doing it wrong?

Tags: c#, memory-management, abstract-class

I'm loading in lots of parts that need to be assigned materials.

I have a list of Materials that I don't want to run to the database each time to get and thought that putting them inside an inherited base might make it easier for me to carry around.

```
public abstract class StoreBase : SecurityBase {

        internal static IEnumerable<AppEntities.Material> materialsList { get; set; }
        internal static IEnumerable<AppEntities.Material> MaterialsList {
            get {
                if (materialsList == null) {                  
                    materialsList = MaterialService.Get().Result;
                }  
                return materialsList;
            }
        }
```

Now anytime I need to load it.. I just call

```
var mats = MaterialList;
```

However, I'm loading in thousands of parts at a time, and my material list is almost 3k items.

Suspicious that this is causing me to have some memory problems, as I can really only load in a few thousand parts before it bottoms out. (x parts times 3k seems to add up fast)

I know there has to be a better solution, but don't know how to achieve without then blowing up the database with queries.

Comment: what language is this?

Comment: @RobK sorry, have updated tags.

Comment: That MaterialsList should be shared among all instances of a particular derived type.

Comment: @HansKesting So all the derived members will only have a reference to that list and not a full list of their own?

Comment: @markokstate - yes, "static" means there is one per type, as opposed to one per instance.

Comment: @HansKesting is it a good practice to make all properties in abstract class static? (like INPC events?)

Comment: @markokstate - NO - you usually *want* per-instance properties. Only use static when you really want just one value for the entire application.